# sending a picture as an MMS

Tags: android, image, mms

I am working on how to send a MMS in android from my app.

i copied an image named image1.png to the sdcard folder in file explorer. its is located in mnt--> sdcard--> image1.png

i run the emulator and scanned the media and i can find the image in the gallery.

now to send the mms i used the following code

...................................................................................

```
    Intent pic = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    pic.putExtra("sms_body", "click the above image");
    String url = "\\sdcard\\image1.png";
    pic.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
    pic.setType("image/png");
    startActivity(pic);
```

...................................................................................

the emulator with the sdcard is already running and now when i run the application it opens up the mms apllication with a TO field and also with the sms body mentioned but the image is not attached.i get the following toast message on my screen

...................................................................................

"sorry you cannot add this picture to your message "

...................................................................................

can anyone help me with this issue?

and i dont understand the concept of uri. can someone help me out.

Many thanks

Comment: The following link will be helpful to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893788/using-android-action-send-to-send-image-via-messenger-and-facebook

Comment: thanks for the link..i tried copy pasting the code mentioned but it shows an error that sendMMS cant have a return type void..

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
Intent pic = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
pic.putExtra("sms_body", "click the above image");

String external = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
String path = "file://" + external + "/image1.png";

pic.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path));
pic.setType("image/png");
startActivity(pic);
```

So actually you need to pre-append the "file://"